# how to get Java on xbox

Tags: java, jar, xbox360, xbox

I was just wondering if there was any way to run a .jar file on xbox. I have the RGH mod and i can transfer files to the xbox via FTP. I have an xbox 360 slim. I've tried some things which I don't completly understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the Xbox to execute java code, there would need to be a JVM implementation specifically for its Architecture (Power PC) and OS (Which is proprietary). Currently, no such JVM exists and therefore there is no way to execute Java byte code on an Xbox 360, no matter what mod you install.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. I just asked to see if i was wrong, thanks for the answer